# Why a simple DateTime conversion does not work in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to take an user input from an ASP.NET webform which is a string and convert that to a `DateTime` in order to save to the database.

The code below seems right, but it does not work. I tried both `Convert.ToDateTime (string)` and `DateTime.Parse (string)`.

Can somebody be so nice to help me see where is the problem?

```
protected void BtnAddMedia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string type = null;
        string title = TextBox1.Text;

        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            type = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString(); 
        }
        else 
        { 
            Response.Write("Please select the type"); 
        }

        string year = TextBox2.Text;

        DateTime productionYear = DateTime.Parse(year);
        // or  DateTime productionYear = Convert.ToDateTime(year);

        Repository r = new Repository();
        r.AddNewMedia(title, type, productionYear);
        Server.Transfer("~/Default.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: `DateTime.Parse(year)` what is the value of year? is it a DateTime, or an integer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime.Parse or Convert.ToDateTime is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597170/datetime-parse-or-convert-todatetime-is-not-working)

Comment: is it just a year?

Comment: I see a big issue in your Exception handling. You catch and handle fatal exceptions, wich is a very bad idea: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: What is the **actuall** string? What is the culture format? Why are you not using something like a DatePicker Element wich would give you a datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your year string contains only a year, you should better use simple string (or even better an integer) for that rather than DateTime object.

still due to any reason, you have to use DateTime then you will need to use `ParseExact` and pass 'yyyy' as date format.

```
DateTime productionYear = DateTime.ParseExact(year, "yyyy" , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it will make a date of 1st January of your specified year.

and whenever you have to display it (obviously you would need to display only year), you can display only date part of it like below.

```
string productionYearInStr = productionYear.ToString("yyyy");
```

Comment: Hello Amit,  your solution worked, thank you very much !